# pass parameters in URL of Zend_Form

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I'm a zend beginner and cant figure out

how to pass parameters and values on a Zend_Form with post Method 
using the setAction() method

controller/action/parameter1/parameter1value/parameter2/paremeter2value

do i need to rewrite routing ?

can anyone tell how this can be achieved
why is zend documentation so horrible ?

Comment: why are you passing values (other then action and method) to your form? The reason may well effect the method you chose to pass the values. setValue() or populate() may be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best approach but this one option:

```
<?php
$form->setAction($form->getView()->url(array('controller' => 'your-controller', 'action' => 'some-action', 'someparam' => 'thevalue')));
?>
```

Is that what youre looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your form inherits from `Zend_Form`, you can pass parameters in when you instantiate the form as follows:

```
$form = new My_Form( array( 'action' => '/controller/action/parameter/' . $parameter,
                            'method' => 'post' ));
```

If you need to access the parameter again when you're processing the submitted form, you can get access to it in the action method of the controller like this:

```
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $parameter = $this->_getParam( 'parameter' );
```

This whole system assumes you have URL re-writing on, but nothing fancy - just the "standard" approach as shown in the "Getting Started" docs.

Although there are differing opinions on the quality of Zend Framework Documentation, I think it is universally agreed that Zend_Form in ZF1 is extremely complicated and hard to learn, so I don't think it would matter how good the doco was, that part of the framework will always be hard to learn.

Comment: Please note that the array() shown in the example posted by @keesschepers is more correct than what I've shown above (my example cheats because it passes in the whole controller/action combo as part of the action value, which is technically incorrect).

Answer (score 0):

this is what's working for me:

In my action method

```
$this->_helper->getHelper('Redirector')->gotoSimple('action','controller', null,
                                                                array(par1 => par1value,
                                                                    par2 => par2value
                                                                    )
                                                            );
```